# Silence out regions of audio based on time stamps passed to sox

Tags: sox

My original question and indirect solution are here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161567/silence-out-regions-of-audio-based-on-a-list-of-time-stamps-using-sox-and-pyth

I have an audio `A` and a bunch of [start ,end] segments `S`. 
I want to pass `S` and `A` to SOX & python so that I can directly silence everything from the audio that is not present in the `S`.

My current solutions relies more on python. I want to use a combination of sox pad/trim commands to achieve this.

I referred : http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html and https://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161567/silence-out-regions-of-audio-based-on-a-list-of-time-stamps-using-sox-and-pyth plus
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208216/create-new-list-from-list-of-lists-in-python-by-grouping

Helped me arrive at the answer.
Thank you